# How to reduce lag when using QStackedWidget in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm attempting to make an application in PyQt5 that will display lots of images in a QStackedWidget, with a separate widget for each image. The images are being scraped from a website and saved to a temp directory on a separate QThread and then the image location is sent back to the main thread using a signal/slot. When the signal is received by the main thread, the image is added to a scroll area on the widget using setWidget().

I'm using a QListWidget for switching the currently displayed page.

My application is working perfectly as expected but I am encountering an annoying lag when switching between items in the QStackedWidget, especially when there's a large number of items in the stack (around 2000 currently). Strangely, this lag seems to go away if I move back through items that have already been the currently displayed item.

Is a QStackedWidget the best way for displaying a large number of widgets like this? Is there possibly something I can do to give priority to switching the currently displayed widget?

Comment: I recommend using QListView

Comment: What is the point of loading **all** of the images when only one of them can be viewed at a time? Just load single images on demand.

Comment: @ekhumoro I'd like to be able to quickly cycle through the images. Would setting the image each time be practical for that purpose?

Comment: Most image viewers work in that way. If the images are not too big, there will be little or no lag. If the images are large, it's obviously impractical to pre-load all the images in a directory, because you'll quickly run out of memory (thumb-nail disk-caches are used to get around that problem). I imagine that some image viewers may use a certain amount of runtime caching for recently viewed full-size images - usually there's a config setting for limiting how much memory the program uses.

Comment: @ekhumoro interesting, I'll give that a go! Thanks very much!